# Binding a function to two events results in function executing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding an accordion tab to open on click and focus. But whenever I click, it executes the function twice. how do i stop this behavior? 
I only want it to execute a single event. either click or focus.

```
$("h2.radioBoxInActive").bind('click focus', function () {
        input = $(this).prev("span, input");
        $(".selected", app.element).removeClass("selected").slideUp();
        $(".radioBoxActive", app.element).removeClass("radioBoxActive");
        $("#" + input.attr("data-panel")).slideDown().addClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("radioBoxActive");
    });
```

Comment: If you click on it, it probably gets the focus...

Comment: I would suggest to bind only focus event

Comment: yes. i want to avoid that. is there a way?

Comment: I would try a workarround. Set a global var to true to avoid execution twice and set it to false on blur event.

Comment: What is the actul use of that? The focus is mostly changed by clicking, so I'd say bind only to one event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid a double execution just bind only `focus` event. This will ensure the execution of the handler even when user is using another input device to select the checkbox (e.g. via keyboard)

Comment: You could also `throttle` the callback function so that it will get executed only once per eg. 100ms.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the timestamp of the last execution to stop the function from executing virtually simulatneously.

This only allows the function to execute if it was last executed more than 50 milliseconds ago.

```
(function(){
    var lastExecuted = 0;
    $("h2.radioBoxInActive").bind('click focus', function () {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeDelta = currentTime - lastExecuted;
        if (timeDelta > 50) {
            lastExecuted = currentTime;
            input = $(this).prev("span, input");
            $(".selected", app.element).removeClass("selected").slideUp();
            $(".radioBoxActive", app.element).removeClass("radioBoxActive");
            $("#" + input.attr("data-panel")).slideDown().addClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("radioBoxActive");
        }
    });
})();
```